# How should I create such a Mask on cv::cuda::GpuMat?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image: wanted mask]

I am trying to create a mask like above in `OpenCV` directly on a `cv::cuda::GpuMat`. I am wondering how to do it. I know the coordinates of 3 points(A, B ,C) already. In CPU version of `OpenCV` I used `cv::fillConvexPoly()`. But in the `CUDA` accelerated namespace there is no equivalence.

Comment: You could use opengl to render a polygon to an image

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-there-a-cuda-version-of-cv-fillconvexpoly/5578